# find nearby in android

Tags: android, location

I have a lot of user in my app, all of them have a fixed location point 
I want to create a new section in which users can see other users who are nearby, just like Messenger Wichet and Bitalk
How can I compare the places together?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find distance between two locations and compare it with your criteria of nearness.

```
if (locationOfMary.distanceTo(locationOfBob) < NEARNESS_CRITERIA) {
    // Locations are near
} else {
    // Locations are far away
}
```

I don't know, maybe PHP already has some libraries for it. If is hasn't, distance between two point you can calculate by the Vincenty's Formula. You can google example of its implementation or see it in `Location.computeDistanceAndBearing()` method from Android SDK.

Since it is an iterative algorithm will be nice to reduce number of calculations. For example, you can apply rough filter to another locations based on the assumption that the distance between two integer values of latitude is 110 km and between two integer values of longitude 110 * cos(latitude).

Good luck!